# Dynamic personalized variable not working with server side JavaScript function

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript

I am doing the following code in ExactTarget landing page:

```
%%[ 
VAR @Rows,@email,@rowCount
SET @Trigger = QUERYPARAMETER("Trigger")
]%%

<script runat="server">  Platform.Load("core", "1");
var DE =  Variable.GetValue("@Trigger");
var NewDE = DataExtension.Init(DE);
var filter = {
    Property: "EmailAddress",
    SimpleOperator: "equals",
    Value: "abc@gmail.com"
};
var data = NewDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter);
if (data.length > 0) {
    Write("<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='3' style='border-collapse:collapse;>");
    for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        var d = data[i];
        Write("<tr>");
        for (var key in d) {
            Write("<td>" + d[key] + "</td>");
        }
        Write("</tr>");
    }
    Write("</table>");} </script>
```

The URL from which I am grabbing value is like..
http://pages.e.mycompanyname.com/Result/?Trigger=abandon_cart24hr

I want to show the  data extension  rows based on selection from form on first landing page. 
This is the code on second landing page. I grabbed the value from url and passing it to JavaScript. But this does not show me any results. Am i  missing something.?

Comment: Please post at least the interesting parts of your URL as well.

Comment: @Timothy..I added the url above...I am just passing a simple parameter from a Form on first landing page.

Comment: Please add %%=v(@Trigger)=%% between your two blocks and verify on your landing page that you see a value for trigger.  Also, your script tage needs to say <script runat="server" language="javascript" >

Comment: Thanks @Timothy..I made the changes and also verified the value for trigger n my page. I figured out the line `var data = NewDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter);` is having some issue. As until before that line everything is working fine.

Comment: You're still missing the single quote in the table tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using the Write() function to debug your inputs.  For this URL, *http://pages.companyname.com/test1?trigger=BirthdayDE&email=abc@gmail.com*, here are the results that I got.

```
%%[
SET @Trigger = QUERYPARAMETER("trigger")
SET @email = QUERYPARAMETER("email")
]%%
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");
    var trigger =  Variable.GetValue("@trigger");
    var email =  Variable.GetValue("@email");
    var DE = DataExtension.Init(trigger);
    var filter = {
        Property: "EmailAddress",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        /* Value: "abc@gmail.com" */
        Value: email
    };
    var data = DE.Rows.Retrieve(filter);
    Write("<br>trigger: " + trigger);
    Write("<br>data.length: " + data.length);

    if (data.length > 0) {

        Write("<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='3' style='border-collapse:collapse;'>");
        for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {

            var d = data[i];
            Write("<tr>");
            for (var i in d) {
                Write("<td>" + d[i] + "</td>");
            }
            Write("</tr>");
        }
        Write("</table>");
    }
</script>
```

[image: page results]